# Circles drawn by points, using trigonometric positions. SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I experimented with SDL_RenderDrawPoint() to draw a circle by drawing its points on its circomference. To do that I expressed their positions (x, y) using sine - and cosine (cos(v), sin(v)) and a for loop drawing each point one degree at a time. with 1080 iterations and a few if-statements I made three circles.

The function:

```
    void DotCircle::DrawCircle()
    {

        if (draw)
        {
            Position = { 500.f, 500.f };
            SDL_Point start;
            start.x = Position.m_x;
            start.y = Position.m_y;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(drawmgr->getRenderer(), 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 1080; i++)
            {
                if (i < 360)
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(drawmgr->getRenderer(), start.x + 300 * cos(i), start.y       + 300 * sin(i));
                }
        
                if (i > 360 )
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(drawmgr->getRenderer(), start.x + 200 * cos(i), start.y   + 200 * sin(i));
                }
                if (i > 720)
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(drawmgr->getRenderer(), start.x + 100 * cos(i), start.y + 100 * sin(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is of course that as the circles radii gets larger the larger room between them, But my question is: Can I make the circles smoother using this technique, and if so, how can I do so?

picture:

[image: link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by converting `i` to radians before passing it to `sin()` and `cos()`.

After that, you might want to consider using an increment smaller than 1 degree, when
you loop over the angles.

If efficiency is a concern, you could speed it up by a factor of 4 by iterating over a 90 degree arc, and taking advantage of symmetry to draw the other three quadrants (and do all three circles in the same iteration, rather than going around 3 times).

Beyond that, there are ways of drawing circles that [don't rely on trigonometry](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Drawing_and_Filling_Circles).

Comment: This improved the circles a lot. now I use a float i and add 0.1*PI/180 (PI = 3.141592653) to i in the loop. The if-statements are also converted into radians. However, can something be done to improve efficiency? I am thinking in the lines of pushing the points into a container and draw them from another place, or perhaps control the frame rate somehow.

I have a square that lags a lot while moving it when the circles are drawn

Comment: I've added a few suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at bresenham algorithm for drawing circles for a pixel by pixel based approach to draw a circle, or to my answer to a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524497/c-sdl2-rendering-a-circle/41570334#41570334).  I'm not an SDL expert, but I post there a program to ASCII draw circles on a text screen with a routine that can be used elsewhere.